# add variable to hex stream

Tags: c#, variables, hex

in c# i want to add variable from trackbar.value to hex stream:

```
            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient("192.168.1.205", 52381);=
        Byte[] sendBytes = new byte[] { 
            0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x81, 0x01, 
            0x04, 0x07, 0x0("trackbar.value"), 0xFF 
        };

        try
        {
            udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
```

ho do i syntax that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a fixed size byte array you can do this:

```
Byte[] sendBytes = new byte[] { 
    0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x81, 0x01, 
    0x04, 0x07, 0x00, 0xFF 
    };

sendBytes[12] = (byte) trackbar.value;
```

**BUT:** This will of course lead to data loss if your trackbar.value is not a byte value and exceeds a maximum value of 255.
So you will either have to reduce precision and scale your value, something like this:

```
byte scaledValue = (byte) ((double) trackbar.value / [maximum_trackbar_value] * 255.0);
```

or increase the amount of bytes used in your message to transfer the value.
For example using a 16bit integer with a maximum value of 65535 (= 2^16 - 1) will require 2 bytes. To "split" your value into these 2 bytes you will have to do a bit shift like this

```
1. sendBytes[12] = (byte) trackbar.value;
2. sendBytes[13] = (byte) (trackbar.value >> 8);
```

The second line will shift the highest 8 bits of the value to the right so they can be put into the next byte, which can only be used for 8 bits, the rest will be cut off. For better understanding:

```
1. (byte) (00000101 00111001) = 00111001
2. (byte) ((00000101 00111001) >> 8) = (byte) (00000000 00000101) = 00000101
```

This will transfer your value in little endian order, meaning the less significant byte ("smaller value") first in your array. You will find more details on that topic here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness. The receiver of your message will have to do the reverse:

```
int trackbarValue = (receivedBytes[12] & 0xFF) | ((receivedBytes[13] & 0xFF) << 8);
```

Here are two functions to make this a little more general:

```
public static byte[] GetBytesLittleEndian(int num, int byteCount)
{
    var result = new byte[byteCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; i++)
    {
        result[i] = (byte)(num >> (i * 8));
    }

    return result;
}

public static int ParseLittleEndian(byte[] data, int byteCount)
{
    int parsed = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; i++)
    {
        parsed |= data[i] << (i * 8);
    }

    return parsed;
}
```

Of course there is build-in functionality for that, see BitConverter.GetBytes() for example, but I think it won't hurt to know some details ;)